# recvfrom() function does not work

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, dns, udp

i had open source cod (this is it's link )
 Visit https://github.com/jtRIPper/dns-tcp-socks-proxy/blob/master/dns_proxy.c 
in this part of cod

```
 while(1) 
    {
        // receive a dns request from the client
        printf("wait for a dns request from the client\n");
        len = recvfrom(sock, buffer->buffer, 2048, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&dns_client, &dns_client_size);
        printf("dns request received\n");


        // fork so we can keep receiving requests
        if (fork() != 0) { continue; }

        // the tcp query requires the length to precede the packet, so we put the length there
        query = malloc(len + 3);
        query[0] = 0;
        query[1] = len;
        memcpy(query + 2, buffer->buffer, len);

        // forward the packet to the tcp dns server
        fprintf(LOG_FILE, "tcp query call\n");
        tcp_query(query, buffer, len + 2);

        // send the reply back to the client (minus the length at the beginning)
        sendto(sock, buffer->buffer + 2, buffer->length - 2, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&dns_client, sizeof(dns_client));

        free(buffer->buffer);
        free(buffer);
        free(query);

        exit(0);
```

, recvfrom() function does not work and i cant continiu and show "dns request received\n"   what is the problem? and then when i use netstat -upan inn command lin i see this

> Active Internet connections (servers and established)
>   Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
>   udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:951           0.0.0.0:*                           1623/rpc.statd
>   udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:54721           0.0.0.0:*                           2214/avahi-daemon: 
>   udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:45085           0.0.0.0:*                           1623/rpc.statd
>   udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           4084/dns_proxy
>   udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           1628/dhclient
>   udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           1582/rpcbind
>   udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           2323/cupsd
>   udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           2214/avahi-daemon: 
>   udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42756           0.0.0.0:*                           1628/dhclient
>   udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1900            0.0.0.0:*                           3306/minissdpd
>   udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:908             0.0.0.0:*                           1582/rpcbind
>   udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                1582/rpcbind
>   udp6       0      0 :::34443                :::*                                1623/rpc.statd
>   udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                2214/avahi-daemon: 
>   udp6       0      0 :::62844                :::*                                1628/dhclient
>   udp6       0      0 :::54654                :::*                                2214/avahi-daemon: 
>   udp6       0      0 :::908                  :::*                                1582/rpcbind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar modification (adding printf after `recvfrom()`) works fine for me. Have you made any other changes to the program, besides the printing?

These are the steps I took to test it:

1. git clone the repo
2. add printfs to source
3. make
4. edit dns_proxy.conf to log somewhere else than /dev/null
5. In another terminal, *ssh someuser@a.box.somewhere -D localhost:9050*
6. *sudo ./dns_proxy*
7. Test with: *host ftp.funet.fi*

BTW. Adding the `printf()` where you suggest produces a lot of output on a desktop where you have other applications like a www-browser or an email client running, so be careful. Maybe you could use the logging convention the rest of the source uses, e.g.

```
if (LOG == 1) { fprintf(LOG_FILE, "Using DNS server: %s\n", inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)&remote_dns)); }
```

BTW2. Remember to take a backup of your /etc/resolv.conf before running dns_proxy, if you have created or edited it manually. Use tailf "your_dns_proxy_logfile.log"  to see whats going on.

BTW3. That program is not very robust. It leaks fds, there is an off-by-one in `string_value()` and the `udp_listener()` does `malloc()` and `memcpy()` without checking the return value of `recvfrom()`. On my machine it segfaults a lot. Seems to just barely function, though.

**EDIT** Here are some changes I made to the original. https://github.com/thuovila/dns-tcp-socks-proxy/ After these modifications it does not segfault for each interrupted `recvfrom()`. The changes have been merged to the upstream repo.

Comment: I don't fully understand step number 5. could you please explain more? what does this command do exactly?

Comment: I think i got it now. I did your instructions step by step and my problem is solved. dns_proxy is running and working fine.

Comment: Okay, great. Glad I could help. It could probably be optimized further, but seems to work OK now.

Answer (score 0):

May be there is no data to receive in the first place. The fact that you cannot see "dns request received\n" means that the recvfrom() call is in blocked state waiting for data to be received. You would need to investigate if hte sender is sending data or not. Next, you probably should recheck if the sock is bound on the right port. You might want to share sender's code and also the recvfrom code where bind happens.

Comment: i open my browser and inter some url for example www.yahoo.com it means that i send request but i dont see any thing in commandline

Comment: You proabably need to do some debugging. If you are running Linux/Windows, can you please check using "netstat -upan" what does the output say? On Linux, it will tell you all the open UDP ports and you should see DNS being one of them. If that works, then the next stop would be to use a packet debugger (like tcpdump/windump) to see if the UDP packet actually makes to your server.

Comment: i have edited the qustion and added the output of netstat -upan command

Comment: Cool! The dns_proxy seems to be running: "udp 0 0 127.0.0.1:53 0.0.0.0:* 4084/dns_proxy". This is same as the LISTEN_PORT (value 53).  What is bothering me is that there is another DNS UDP connection: "udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:68 0.0.0.0:* 1628/dhclient" For this one, the DHCP server is sitting on port 68. Is your DNS request going to the server sitting on port 68? Are you getting the URLs resolved in the browser? At this point, I would recommend doing a tcpdump and verifying hte port number in the DNS request.

Comment: Can you investigate if you have another DNS server running and try switching it off.

Comment: The dns_proxy overwrites /etc/resolv.conf so any application using the normal dns resolver libraries will revert to using UDP localhost:53. The avahi daemon listens for mdns. Depending on the order defined in /etc/nsswitch.conf that is done either before or after regular dns lookup, but in either case anything not present in mdns should be resolved from the dns_proxy.